# Split the entries of a column to multiple other columns with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have several entries (i.e. 128) in a column of a worksheet and want to divide them into a number of new columns on a different sheet. I have already found some code by KuTools for Excel, but it's not exactly working the way I want it to. 
With this Code:

```
Sub SplitColumn()
'Updateby20141106
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim xRow As Integer
Dim xCol As Integer
Dim xArr As Variant
xTitleId     = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type: = 8)
xRow         = Application.InputBox("Rows :", xTitleId)
Set OutRng   = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type: = 8)
Set InputRng = InputRng.Columns(1)
xCol         = InputRng.Cells.Count / xRow
ReDim xArr(1 To xRow, 1 To xCol + 1)
For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
    xValue = InputRng.Cells(i + 1)
    iRow = i Mod xRow
    iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
    xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = xValue
Next
OutRng.Resize(UBound(xArr, 1), UBound(xArr, 2)).Value = xArr
End Sub
```

which is basically great, I can split the column into a variable amount of new columns, depending on the number of rows each column should consist of. Nevertheless I would like the values to 1. be links to the actual values (i.e. $A$1 instead of 1) and 2. to be divided to the new columns column by column. So that newColumn 1 gets the link of A1 in its first row, newColumn 2 gets the link of A2 and so on.
My biggest wish would be, to be able to define the amount of rows for every new column (i.e. new column 1 gets 10 rows, new column 2 gets 7 etc.) and that these would still be filled in row by row.

Thank you very much for your help!
Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little contradictory. If you want the output to work left to right first, then you can't have varying lengths of column.

Here is how I'd change the main output loop to create a link rather than a value to the source data.

```
For i = 0 To InputRng.Cells.Count - 1
    iRow = i Mod xRow
    iCol = VBA.Int(i / xRow)
    xArr(iRow + 1, iCol + 1) = "='" & InputRng.Cells(i + 1).Parent.Name & "'!" & InputRng.Cells(i + 1).Address
Next
```

Comment: Wow that was fast and it is working like a charm! Thank you so much. Refering to the contradictory part of my question: it would be the absolute best to be able to define for each of the new columns, how many rows they should contain, but i guess this would require endless loops and if-then conditions. Do you have any idea how to achieve the division of the rows of the original column to the new ones left to right, without the feature of defining , how many rows the new columns should contain?

Comment: ok, I guess the division of the values from left to right can be managed by just transposing the columns to rows. Do you know a more elegant way?